# Is this a elided sentence?

Tags: ellipsis

The original sentence:

> Populations increase and decrease relatively not only to one another,
>   but also to natural resources.

Is it an elided version of something like:

> Populations increase and decrease relatively not only **[relating]** to one another, but also **[relating]** to natural resources.

Comment: No i don't think so. It's just a mere modification of "relatively to" in my opinion!

Comment: @Cardinal, do you think "relatively to" is the adverb version of  "relative to" in this case?

Comment: Other phrases you could expand it to include *in relation to* and *as they relate to*. The problem with analyzing elision in non-parallel constructions is that there is often more than a single possibility. As such, it's impossible to point to any *specific* elision. However, in this case it would sound incredibly awkward to add any of those—unless you rephrased the sentence to remove the initial *relatively*.